# How to update data in reducer state in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

this is my reducer. I want to update my data in reducer without duplication, based on ID.

Can anyone please help me.

This is my code :

```
export  const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_DATA:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
    data: [
      ...(state.data.filter(item => (item.id !== action.payload.id))), 
      action.payload
    ]
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

I want to delete id : 2 and want to add new data into the state.

```
var state = {
   data: [
     {id: 1, data: "Hello"}, {id: 2, data: "World"}
   ]
}
var payload= {id:2, data: "SO"}
var data1 = state.data.map(function(item){return (item.id == payload.id)? payload: item})

var data = {...state,
               data: data1
             }
console.log(data);
```

It should be updated as,

```
var state = {
   data: [
     {id: 1, data: "Hello"}, {id: 3, data: "Value"}
   ]
}
```

Comment: what is hapening now and what do you expect

Comment: I have some data in my reducer state, I want to overwrite the data based on ID.

Comment: Could you post how the data looks like? or how id-s are arranged inside it?

Comment: export  const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
         switch(action.type) {
            case types.UPDATE_DATA:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: [
      ...(state.data.filter(item => (item.id !== action.payload.id))), 
      action.payload
    ]
    default:
        return state;
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will update the data. if it matches any of the object in array.

```
   export  const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
        switch(action.type) {
        case types.UPDATE_DATA:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
               data: state.data.map(item => {
                   return item.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : item;
               }); // replace matched item and returns the array 
            }); 
        default:
            return state;
        }
    }
```

if you want to delete previous and add new data then you can try this once.

```
 export  const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
        switch(action.type) {
        case types.UPDATE_DATA:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
               data: state.data.filter(item => {
                   return item.id !== action.id; //delete matched data
               }).concat(action.payload); //concats new data
            }); 
        default:
            return state;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this basically means replacing the item with payload if it matches.

Comment: It's working. But the problem is, if I updated first id, second id is going to first index place, then third id is going to second index place.

It should replace first index, if I'm updating first data.

Comment: yeah isn't is something that you wanted??

Comment: ok i got your point. so you want to put new object in place of the one that matches the `action.id` right? If thats the case you can change `action.payload.id` to `action.id` in first code block. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well you solution depends on the way you data object is organised. If your data object is as given in the example below then using the spread operator syntax and map works well.

```js
var state = {
   data: [
     {id: 1, data: "Hello"}, {id: 2, data: "World"}
   ]
}
var payload= {id:2, data: "SO"}
var data1 = state.data.map(function(item){return (item.id == payload.id)? payload: item})

var data = {...state,
               data: data1
             }
console.log(data);
```

Your code

```
export  const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_DATA:
        var temp =  state.data.map(function(item){return (item.id == action.payload.id)? action.payload: item})
        return {...state,
          data: temp
        }
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: But, I want to delete old data & want to add new data into it. I have mentioned avove.

Comment: where are you specifying which id you need to delete

Comment: I'm passing ID in action.id